# $\mathcal M = \{z \in \mathbb C | |z|=r \}$ , where $r \in \mathbb R , r >0$

Tags: complex-numbers

**The statement of the problem :** Consider the set $\mathcal M = \{  z \in \mathbb C |   |z|=r\} $  , where $r \in \mathbb R , r >0$

**a)** Prove that there exists $a,b \in \mathcal M,a \neq b$ such that $a+b \in \mathcal M$.

**b)** Find the values ​​of the positive integer $n \geq 2$ for which there exists a subset $\mathcal S \subseteq \mathcal M$, with n elements, so that $u+v \in \mathcal M , \forall u,v \in \mathcal S,u \neq v$.

**My approach:** First of all, the set $\mathcal M$ consists of all the affixes of the points located on the circle with the center in the coordinate system and the radius **r**. To prove the point **a)**, I chose a point on the axis $Oy$ with coordinates $(0,\frac{r}{2})$, then I took the parallel to the $Ox$ axis. It is obvious that this will intersect the circle in two points, symmetrical to the $Oy$ axis. According to the parallelogram rule, the sum of these affixes will be in $(0,r)$, which is on the circle, so I proved point **a)**, below I put a picture that suggests my reasoning :

[image]

Now at **b)** I encountered some problems and I didn't really know which approach to take, but I think that the solution is also a geometric one.

Any and all proofs will be helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `\{` and `\}` to get { and } in MathJax

Comment: Where did this exercise come from?

Comment: An old collection of problems, which I contacted the book publisher but they no longer have the officials solutions, so I'm trying to do them by myself and the help of others more insightful :)

Comment: Very pretty;  I suggest that we replace $r$ with $1$;This is of little importance and will avoid dragging $r$ in the calculations; The angle between two points is $\frac{2\pi}3$ according to the trigo formulas

Comment: So you want to prove that there are at most 3 different points in the unit circle, so that the sum of any 2 is also one of these 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take $r=1$, which doesn't change the generality of the problem.

Let $p,q \in \mathbb R$ such that $e^{i p}=u\neq v=e^{iq}$

$$u+v\color{red}{\textbf=}2\cos(\frac{p-q}2)e^{i\frac{p+q}2}\in \mathcal {M}\iff p-q=\pm\frac{2\pi}3$$
$\color{red}{\text{based}}$ on [trigonometry formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

Then $v=ju$ or $v=j^2u$, with $ j:=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3} }$

Let us then have a third point $w$ that meets our requirements:
We have $w=j^2u $ or $w=ju$.

Our reasoning shows that the sets we are looking for belong to$$\{\color{red}{\{}\{u,ju\},\{u,j^2u\},\{u,ju,j^2u\}\color{red}{\}}, \text{with } u\in\mathcal M\}$$

$\text{The set of possible numbers is }\{2,3\}$.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: I really enjoyed this exercise. Thank you

Comment: if you liked this one, you will also find this geometry problem that can be solved with complex numbers interesting
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866434/geometry-problem-where-the-solution-involves-the-use-of-some-properties-of-compl
I encountered some problems at point b), that's why I also put a bounty so it can get a nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

The key idea is to use the position vectors of the points on the circle.

2 vectors with magnitude $r$ will add up to a vector with magnitude $r$ iff the angle between the vectors is 120°.
So the angle between the position vectors of any pair of points in $\mathcal{S}$ should be 120°.

Also, as the sum of the angles about any point (the origin of the argand plane, in our case) is 360°, we can have at most three points in $\mathcal{S}$.

As a particular example, for $n = 3$, $\mathcal{S} = \{r, r\omega, r{\omega}^2\}$ works, where $\omega$ is the complex root of unity.

Comment: $\omega = cos(2pi/3) + isin(2pi/3) $ ?

Comment: if so , the $1 + \omega = - \omega^2 $

Comment: @LastX: $-\omega^2\in \mathcal M$

Comment: I built a drawing, and I realized, because $|\omega ^2| = |- \omega ^2| = 1$ . Thanks !